# How can I do remove these bumps?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I was watching a youtube tutorial video recently on character modeling, I and decided to try to model a character.
I decided to try to model a crewmate from Among Us, but when I turned my model into a mesh, there were these bumps near the feet of the model. Is there any way to remove them?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Sam, it would be great if you could include a screen-grabbed illustration of your 'bumps'. Then folks could decide whether they have any idea of what's going on before downloading your file.

Answer (score 0):

The topology is not good, and your mesh is high-poly, which makes any change tedious. You should better work with a low-poly mesh with a *Mirror* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Here I just un-subdivided your mesh, kept the top and changed the bottom, it could be a start:

[image]